# ERROR: unable to write data: [Errno 32] Broken pipe (proc_open)

Tags: php, pipe, proc-open

I try to run a code (its working on other machine fine) but one of the machine its not working!

```
    <?php
    $descriptorspec = array(
       0 => array("pipe", "r"),  // stdin is a pipe that the child will read from
       1 => array("pipe", "w"),  // stdout is a pipe that the child will write to
       2 => array("file", "tmp/error-output.txt", "a") // stderr is a file to write to
    );
    $command = "/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl --restrict-filenames -f m4a https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=youtubeid --output - | /home/youtube/public_html/bin/ffmpeg-linux-64bit -i - -b:a 128k -f mp3 /home/youtube/public_html/mp3_cache/k/filename.mp3";

    if(is_resource($process = proc_open($command, $descriptorspec, $pipes))) {

        fwrite($pipes[0], '<?php print_r($_ENV); ?>');
        fclose($pipes[0]);

        echo stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
        fclose($pipes[1]);

        // It is important that you close any pipes before calling
        // proc_close in order to avoid a deadlock
        $return_value = proc_close($process);

        echo "command returned $return_value\n";
    }
```

Output of "error-output.txt" file:

```
[youtube] koUEv1anTb8: Downloading webpage
[youtube] koUEv1anTb8: Downloading video info webpage
[youtube] koUEv1anTb8: Extracting video information
[youtube] koUEv1anTb8: Downloading MPD manifest
[download] Destination: -

[download]   0.0% of 5.14MiB at Unknown speed ETA Unknown ETA
[download]   0.1% of 5.14MiB at Unknown speed ETA Unknown ETA

ERROR: unable to write data: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
sh: line 1: 36828 Done(1)                 /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl --    restrict-filenames -f m4a https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=youtubeid --output -
     36829 Segmentation fault      | /home/youtube/public_html/bin/ffmpeg-linux-64bit -i - -b:a 128k -f mp3 mp3_cache/k/filename.mp3
```

I Don't know what i am doing wrong, can some body point out what exactly the problem?

Is there another way to execute this code instead of using PIPEs?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for this problem, in latest Linux OS somehow you can't run root and user uploaded binary file using exec or proc_open (etc..) in a single command.

I hope this will help other people.

Answer (score 0):

This error indicates that broken pipe between two commands. So first command output is wrong or data format is incorrect.
Example:-

```
dpkg -s apache2 | grep Status
```

grep command takes input from first command. If first command successful then other command can read input otherwise error. I run lots of these types of commands with php proc_open function in non blocking mode. You can also use operators between commands also worked.

```
 ; Run all as a separate commands 
 && Run Second Command if first successful
 || Run Second Command If First Failed
```